# Syntax error that makes no sense to me

Tags: java

I was just starting a small program for fun and I got the error
`Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token` after the static int declaration.

```
class Counter {
    public static int counter;  

    for(;;) {

    }
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Java classes consist of methods and blocks. can't have raw statements like for(;;)

Answer (score 3):

The `for` statement should be in a code block such as method rather than the class block

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `for` statement and body in a method.